# WPF DataBinding of list to DataGrid - no update of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, auto-update

i just started programming with WPF and have the problem that the datagrid in the WPF will not be updated the values. I already tried differing things for a couple of days but unfortunately nothing worked at the end. The binding for itself does work when the GUI will be stared. I add a button to add new data to the datagrid. The data will be updated in the list, but not in the datagrid. It would be very kind if someone could help me.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        ObservableCollection<Person> obsCol = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;           

            Person pers = new Person();
            pers.Name = "Tom";
            pers.Gender = "m";
            list.Add(pers);

            pers = new Person();
            pers.Name = "Bianca";
            pers.Gender = "w";
            list.Add(pers);

            obsCol = new ObservableCollection<Person>(list);

            grid.ItemsSource = obsCol;
        }

        private void Bt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Person pers = new Person();
            pers.Name = "Andreas";
            pers.Gender = "m";
            list.Add(pers);
            obsCol = new ObservableCollection<Person>(list);

            int u = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Person.cs:

```
public class Person:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "Name"); }
    }

    private string gender;

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set { gender = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "Gender"); }
    }

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // OnPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
    ObservableCollection<Person> obsCol = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;           

        Person pers = new Person();
        pers.Name = "Tom";
        pers.Gender = "m";
        list.Add(pers);

        pers = new Person();
        pers.Name = "Bianca";
        pers.Gender = "w";
        list.Add(pers);

        obsCol = new ObservableCollection<Person>(list);

        grid.ItemsSource = obsCol;
    }

    private void Bt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person pers = new Person();
        pers.Name = "Andreas";
        pers.Gender = "m";
        list.Add(pers);
        obsCol = new ObservableCollection<Person>(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Bt1_Click add

```
grid.ItemsSource = obsCol;
```

at the end

Comment: That was maybe too easy :-p. And yes it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new collection. Instead, add the new Person object to the existing one:

```
private void Bt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pers = new Person
    {
        Name = "Andreas",
        Gender = "m"
    };

    obsCol.Add(pers);
}
```

If required, clear the collection before adding new data, by

```
obsCol.Clear();
```

---

EDIT: Of course you do not at all need the `list` member:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> obsCol
    = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this; // this seems also pointless       

    grid.ItemsSource = obsCol;

    var pers = new Person
    {
        Name = "Tom",
        Gender = "m"
    };
    obsCol.Add(pers);

    pers = new Person
    {
        Name = "Bianca",
        Gender = "w"
    };
    obsCol.Add(pers);
}
```

The DataContext assignment would be useful only if you had a Binding to a property, like

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> ObsCol { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

with this XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ObsCol}" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks for your good hint, of course I dont need to create a new collection if I add one item to the collection. It is always neccessary to bind the collection to the datagrid instead of the list, isn't it?

Comment: `grid.ItemsSource = obsCol;` is not binding, just an assignment. It is however sufficient when you later only modify the existing collection. And of course you don't need the other list at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to seperate the ViewModel from the Code-Behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs) and only init the ViewModel there.

I would do the binding in the Xaml. So, my MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppAddPerson.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="add andreas" x:Name="ButtonAddAndreas" Click="ButtonAddAndreas_OnClick" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfAppAddPerson
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainWindowViewModel _vm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
            DataContext = _vm;
        }

        private void ButtonAddAndreas_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var p = new Person
            {
                Name = "Andreas",
                Gender = "m"
            };

            _vm.Persons.Add(p);

        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel (MainWindowViewModel.cs):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WpfAppAddPerson.Annotations;

namespace WpfAppAddPerson
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

            var p1 = new Person
            {
                Name = "Tom",
                Gender = "m"
            };

            Persons.Add(p1);

            var p2 = new Person
            {
                Name = "Bianca",
                Gender = "w"
            };

            Persons.Add(p2);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the person class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WpfAppAddPerson.Annotations;

namespace WpfAppAddPerson
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _gender;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Gender
        {
            get => _gender;
            set { _gender = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehnsive ideas and changes. I see I still have to learn a lot about programming of WPF's. The most important question I dont understand is, why do you use two different PropertyCahnged events. Is the one on the class 'Person' not enough?

Comment: You are right. For this simple example PropertyChanged in MainWindiwViewModel is not necessary. As I started typeing I thought I woul have at least one further Item in the MainWindow. ObservableCollections fire OnPropertyChanged by itself. The event in the class person is only fired when you change name or gender of the person. Not if you change the collection.